# Detecting whenever socket disconnected using select()

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I'm trying to detect whenever client has been disconnected with select() function. The problem is that, I don't quite much understood how select() does work. I'm using following code, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and/or how to detect if client is disconnected?
I'm using non-blocking sockets.

```
int Network::bytesAvailable()
{
    long bytes = 0;

    if(ioctl(this->sockfd, FIONREAD, &bytes) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Network:bytesAvailable: ioctl() call failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return bytes;
}

NetworkStatus Network::status()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set  fd;
    int result = 0;

    tv.tv_sec  = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&fd);
    FD_SET(this->sockfd, &fd);

    result = select(this->sockfd + 1, &fd, 0, 0, &tv);

    if(result && !this->bytesAvailable())
    {
        return -1; // disconnected, I'm guessing this is definitely WRONG.
    }
    else if(result > 0 && FD_ISSET(this->sockfd, &fd))
    {
        return 1; // bytes available.
    }
    else if(!result)
    {
        return 0; // timeout
    }

    return -1; // select() call failed.
}
```

Comment: Generally we detect, Whether connection live? using `keepalive` and   `select()` we use for multiplexing. Is it **not** correct?

Comment: I don't understand your grammar, excuse me :)

Comment: Sorry my English is very much poor :( but I edited comment, Am I understood now?

Comment: Nope, I'm really sorry :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a socket closes it becomes "readable" but calling `recv` will return 0 bytes. Using `select` you can tell when the socket can be read then when reading it if `recv` returns 0 then you know it has closed.

Your comment "bytes available" isn't exactly accurate. The socket may be read from however, if it is closed there will be no bytes available.

```
else if(result > 0 && FD_ISSET(this->sockfd, &fd))
{
    return 1; // bytes available.
}
```

In non-blocking sockets, `recv` will return -1 and set `errno` to `EWOULDBLOCK` (or `EAGAIN`) if there is no data and the socket is not closed.

Comment: AFAIK on non-blocking sockets, it's not correct, because recv can return 0 (no data has been received yet).